# not able to login using sandbox personal account when payinhg to sandbox account

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am not able to login sandbox personel account then try to do payment process.

I have set my test business a/c as business email address.
When it redirect site to [https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ae/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=*flow&SESSION=EfPl7uvcjBv*](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ae/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=EfPl7uvcjBv_)...

When I use sanbox personal account, it always show me "Please check your email address and password and try again" even though it is correct.

any way that some one linked this accounts to others sandbox account ?

Please advice why this happne.

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me once. I think I used multitabbed browsing and was still logged with my business account. This produced certain amount of cookies stored locally :-) and the login with the personal account was refused.

Close the tabs, clean up all PP cookies and give it another try.